# using Raphael JS to scale a group of elements at once

Tags: javascript, svg, raphael

I have a simple scene in Raphael JS which contains mainly basic elements, circles, rect, images, etc.

I want to scale up a circle on the mouseover event, which I can do, but I want to add an image over the top of the circle and have that scale as well when the mouse is over the circle OR the image.

Is there a way that I can scale two (or X) items instead of one at a time? Is there some kind of "container" element that I cant find?

Also, when then mouse is over the circle, the event fires, but then when the mouse goes over the image, the mouseout event of the circle fires, how can I stop this so that it looks like the circle and image are one element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you have to do here is create a transparent circle over the circle/image combination you already have. So, circle,image,circle. The second circle is where you put your event handling. By doing it this way, the top transparent circle will get focus even when it looks like you're hovering over the image.

Stick the lot of them in a set and scale the set in the mouseover. I'd do an example for you, but I'm inherently lazy. If you're really stuck, I'll give it a go.

Hope that makes sense.

Comment: thanks i'll give that a shot, is a `set` just a logical container that you can perform events and junk on?

Comment: A set is a logical grouping. You use it to apply the same transformations to a group of objects. Each object within is transformed individually. It's worth noting that, as on occasion you might get unanticipated results. See http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html#Paper.set for more information